# Bootstrap popover in gsp <g:each> tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, gsp

I'm fairly new to Javascript, which I think is where my problem is here.  I would like to use Bootstrap popovers to show a list of links specific to the data for a popup.   So to use the standard Books/Authors example, I would like to show  a popup for each author that has links to all their books.  Inside my table, I have:

```
<g:each in="${authors}" var="author">
    <tr>
        <td>${author.name}</td>
        <td>
            <a type="link" class="link popovers" title="Books"
                data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
                data-content="to be overwritten">Author's Books
         </td>
     </tr>
     <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
         <div>
             <g:render template="bookList" model="[data : author.bookList]"/>
         </div>
     </div>
</g:each>
```

and a script to put the template in the popover:

```
 $(function (){
     $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover (
        {html:true,
         trigger: 'click',
         content : function() {
             return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        })
});
```

Assuming my template works correctly (which it appears to), this still only shows the data for the first Author for all popovers.   What do I need to do to make the correct popover show for each author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same id "popover_content_wrapper" for all your authors. Try using the status attribute to give each author popover content a unique id like this:

```
<g:each in="${authors}" var="author" status="i">
    <tr>
        <td>${author.name}</td>
        <td>
            <a type="link" class="link popovers" title="Books"
                data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
                data-contentId="popover_content_wrapper_${i}"
                data-content="to be overwritten">Author's Books
         </td>
     </tr>
     <div id="popover_content_wrapper_${i}" style="display: none">
         <div>
             <g:render template="bookList" model="[data : author.bookList]"/>
         </div>
     </div>
</g:each>
```

Then

```
$(function (){     
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").each(function( index ) {
            var contentId = $( this ).data('contentId');
            var contentElement = $("#" + contentId);

            $(this).popover ({html:true,
                 trigger: 'click',
                 content : function() {
                     return contentElement.html();
                })
            });

});
```

Comment: Thank you.   In mine I needed to put the popover_content_wrapper div before the declaration of the popover, I'm not sure if I was doing something wrong.

Also, is that '.danger' correct?  Shouldn't that be an identifier of some type from above?

Comment: Yup. Updated the selector.